# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error 111

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know there are quite a few questions with the same error here, but none of them refers to the same scenario as mine so please - do not mark it as duplicate.

I have a dedicated server with HeartInternet and I host around 50 websites on it.
For connection I use PHP PDO and the NON persistent connection.

A few times a day all of the websites are down displaying the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading
>   initial communication packet', system error: 111

HeartInternet says that it's nothing to do with them and I know the code for the database wrapper is written properly. Any idea what might be causing it?

Could the fact that there are 50 sites hosted on one machine have something to do with it? Should we use MySQL cluster for this sort of volume?

Comment: Are you sure your hostname is corrent?

Comment: Your server might be going down. Setup a montiter like http://uptimerobot.com/ to check availability of your server.

Comment: @Daan - yes - it's all on the same server - 'localhost'

Comment: @JayBhatt - the server is up when this is happening - but it might be that mysql server is down. I don't think this monitor checks for database server?

Comment: @SpencerMark I was refereeing to database server and the monitor checks using various methods like ping, HTTP, open ports, and you can also check by setting up an account.